# "ICD file not working" error

Tags: windows-7, gaming

I'm on Windows 7. I installed FIFA 2001 from an ISO file, mounted it on a virtual drive (since it was asking for a CD-ROM), and tried launching the game. I get a "FIFA2001.ICD has stopped working" error. I tried tinkering with the executable's Compatibility options (Win XP mode, Run as Admin), but none of this works. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into whether the game has some copy protection that's detecting use of a virtual drive and deliberately causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

Is your ISO File Healthy ?!
Some time Compatibility mode isn't useful. Anyway Read following link From `EAGames`:

> https://help.ea.com/article/cd-rom-troubleshooting